# How to fix all similar warnings using Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

Following warnings appear at multiple places in the solution when FxCop in run on a large project:

"All reference arguments passed to externally visible methods should be checked against null (Nothing in VB). If appropriate, throw a System.ArgumentNullException when the argument is null."

One way to fix them is to go to every method with such warnings and use ReSharper to write code to check the argument for null.

Is there any idea so that I can use ReSharper only once and fix all such warnings at once?

Comment: You can try `Resharper->Inspect->Code issues in Project/Solution` to get it listed and get fix it one by one from there by resharper. I am not sure how confident one can be to use search and replace. If you still feel you need to use search and replace you can use `SearchWithPttern`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "Apply fix to all problems" feature. Since throwing the ArgumentNull exception will change the standard behavior of your methods, Resharper 'helps' you by preventing you from just bulk applying these types of changes.

Some methods might just accept null as a value and don't need to throw an exception, some methods might handle null in a completely different way... So Resharper can't decide what's best for you, it just tells you that you might want to add a null check and by default such a check will throw an exception if you let Resharper implement it..